# Pandas - How do you find the top n elements of 1 column based on a condition from another column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am struggling with a question based on Pandas. I have an earthquake data set with columns of countries and magnitudes. I am asked to:
"Find the top 10 states / countries where the strongest and weakest
earthquakes occurred."

From this question, I garnered that I am meant to find the top 10 countries ["country"] with the highest values (value_counts) , but sorting by magnitude ["mag"].

How would I go about doing this? I've looked around but there's nothing I've found about this online.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Say you have two countries. Country A has ten magnitude 4 earthquakes a year. Country B has one magnitude 5 earthquake a year. Should country A get sorted above or below country B? If the answer is below, then the number of earthquakes does not matter - only the very largest one, which means you don't need value_counts().

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did not find something useful? If I understand your question correct, it is a simple one. After creating a dataframe by using below methods, you will get what you need.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(".csv") 
df.nlargest(x, ['Column Name'])
```

x is the number of elements which are the largest ones.
Same is goes for nsmallest too. Just use these:

```
DataFrame.nsmallest(n, columns, keep='first')
DataFrame.nlargest(n, columns, keep='first')
```

Please read and check the documentation first.

Comment: Thank You! Based on the vague wording of the question, you may be right, as by using nlargest/nsmallest you do get the 10 strongest/weakest earthquakes. I personally am very confused by the wording, but I hope this works?

Comment: may i ask, what is wrong with the wording of this solution ?  it looks very standard and quite complete.  Import `pandas`. make a dafaframe (`df`).  Read in a `*.csv` file.  get the n largest points in a given dataframe column....